# Popup control keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have a RadioButton that open popup when checked it.

```
<StackPanel>
 <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonSave" IsChecked="{Binding IsSave}">Save</RadioButton>
 <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButtonNotSave"  IsChecked="{Binding IsSave,Converter={StaticResource ToNegativeConverter}}">Not Save</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
<Popup x:Name="Popup" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=RadioButtonNotSave}" StaysOpen="False" Placement="Left" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=RadioButtonNotSave}">  
 <StackPanel>
  <TextBox x:Name="PopupTextBox" />
 </StackPanel>
</Popup>
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" />
```

I want to focused PopupTextBox when Opened Popup, and focused TextBox when Closed Popup.(My project is Keyboard base).

I use This code for focuse.

```
public class SetFocusTrigger : TargetedTriggerAction<Control>
{
 protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
  {
    if (Target == null) return;

    Target.Focus();
  }
}
```

and in xaml

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Opened">
        <local:SetFocusTrigger TargetName="PopupTexBox"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closed">
        <local:SetFocusTrigger TargetName="TexBox"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

It is ok, but when open popup RadioButtonNotSave lost checked and RadioButtonSave is checked!!!

Comment: RadioButtonNotSave lost and RadioButtonSave are bound to a "IsSave" property (i assume a property of the object used as datacontext). Check what part of your code will change that property under which circumstances and you will know what is going on. The triggers in your question do not seem to be related to manipulations of the "IsSave" property.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this scenario:

```
<Window x:Class="RadioButtonsStack.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler"/>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <RadioButton x:Name="RadioBtn" Content="TestPopup"/>
        <Popup x:Name="myPopup" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=RadioBtn, Mode=OneWay}" Placement="Mouse" StaysOpen="False">
            <Border Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBox x:Name="tbPopup" Text="inside popup"/>
            </Border>
            <Popup.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Popup">
                    <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="myPopup_LostFocus"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myPopup, Path=IsOpen}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=tbOutsidePopup}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Popup.Style>
        </Popup>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbOutsidePopup" Margin="20" Text="outside popup"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void EventSetter_OnHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myPopup.IsOpen = true;
        tbPopup.Focusable = true;
        Keyboard.Focus(tbPopup);
    }

    private void myPopup_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbOutsidePopup.Focusable = true;
        Keyboard.Focus(tbOutsidePopup);
    }
}
```

You basically start with the outsideTextBox focused with the help of this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=myPopup, Path=IsOpen}" Value="False">
     <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=tbOutsidePopup}"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

When the Popup is opened you change the focus in the handler:

```
tbPopup.Focusable = true;
Keyboard.Focus(tbPopup);
```

And on Popup LostFocus handler you change again the focus:

```
<EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="myPopup_LostFocus"/>

tbOutsidePopup.Focusable = true;
Keyboard.Focus(tbOutsidePopup);
```

I know it's not elegant, in fact i tried a few bindings there and i didn't succeed. This is the way i see it now.

Comment: Tnhaks, tbPopup get focuse when opened Popop, but when i click enter tbOutsidePopup focused, and another controls in poput don't get focuse.

Comment: @ar.gorgin i thought you want to focus the outside TextBox immediately after the Popup is closed.

Comment: Yes, i have 3 textbox in popup, when popup opend first textbox get focuse but when press enter for got to next textbox ii go to textbox that in out of popup.